# Django ORM: Why is exclude() so slow and how to optimize it?

Tags: django, postgresql, orm

I have the following 3 queries in my CBV:

```
filtered_content = Article.objects.filter_articles(search_term)
filtered_articles = filtered_content.exclude(source__website=TWITTER)
filtered_tweets = filtered_content.filter(source__website=TWITTER)
```

Short explanation:
I'm querying my database (PostgreSQL) for all article titles that contain the search term. After that, I separate the results into one variable that contains all articles originating from Twitter and the other variable contains all articles originating from all other websites.

I have two questions about optimizing these queries.

**Question 1:** Looking at the average time it takes to run these queries, it doesn't make sense to me (filtered_content = less than 0.001 seconds, filtered_articles = 0.2 seconds and filtered_tweets = 0.04 seconds).
What is the reason for the exclude() statement (filtered_articles) being so slow?
I also tried doing the query in another way, but this was even slower:

```
filtered_content = Article.objects.filter_articles(search_term)
filtered_tweets = filtered_content.filter(source__website=TWITTER)
filtered_content.exclude(article_id__in=[tweet.article_id for tweet in filtered_tweets])
```

**Question 2:** Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem / is there a way to do it in less than 3 separate queries? More specifically, using the Django ORM, is there a way to do a query where all excluded() objects are stored in one variable while all non-excluded objects are stored in another?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why is it slower, maby you need to inspect sql that exclude generates. On the other hand you can try with Q statment:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Article.objects.filter(~Q(source__website=TWITTER)).filter_articles(search_term)
```

can you share yours .filter_articles() method?

Comment: filter_articles is a ModelManager method that I created for the Article model                                                                          
 def filter_articles(self, search_term):
        return self.filter(title__search=search_term).select_related('source', 'source__sector', 'tweet_type', 'source__website').order_by('-pub_date')